# Spring Boot No string type field can have spaces before or after the data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Send an error message when some string type field can have spaces before or after the data when they are sent by POST

I tried using the NotBlank annotation, but it does not validate that a string contains spaces at the end or beginning of the data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it in the following way.
Create a validation:

```
 @Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = NoSpacesValidator.class)
    public @interface NoSpaces {
    
        String message() default "The value must not contain leading or trailing spaces";
    
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    
     Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }



  public class NoSpacesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NoSpaces, String> {
    
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            if (value == null) {
                return true;
            }
            return value.trim().equals(value);
        }
    }
```

And in the entity use the annotation "NoSpaces"

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@NotBlank
@NoSpaces
private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following condition, or just use the `trim` method to trim the leading and trailing whitespace:

```java
      yourString.startsWith(" ") || yourString.endsWith(" ")
```